# How can a speaker be designed so that it stops moving as fast as possible when the music stops?

Tags: sound-design, sound, speakers

How can a speaker be designed so it can dissipate energy and stop vibrating as quickly as possible? For example, when classical musicians are playing loudly but stops suddenly, dampening their instruments, and it is important for speakers to stop moving as fast as possible?

Comment: The term you're looking for is *damping factor*, and it is related to both the speaker system (including the driver(s), enclosure, and electronics) and the connected amplifier. See: http://www.crownaudio.com/media/pdf/amps/damping_factor.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_factor and http://www.audioholics.com/audio-amplifier/damping-factor-effects-on-system-response, etc.